# How to connect a handset to a computer for VoIP

Tags: usb, audio, voip

I'm trying to move away from having physical phones to just using softphones on my desktop computers. I know there are a *ton* of great headset options, but I don't really want to go that route. I would like to stick with a more traditional handset.

The problem is that I can't seem to find anything good.

- [Jabra 450](https://www.jabra.com/business/office-headsets/jabra-handset-450): looks good but it's DECT which I want to avoid and it's expensive
- [Plantronics Calisto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SNM7CQW): could work, but also a bit pricy
- [Generic USB Handset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FIH4FQ): something like this seems promising, but every one I've found has bad reviews

The other idea I had was to get a traditional phone handset and then use something like [this](https://smile.amazon.com/Sennehsier-USB-RJ9-Headset-Connection-Cable/dp/B00O1AKCJE/) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LWXM1ON) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FYV8J7B) to connect it to a computer. But, that feels like a hack with lots of ways it could fail.

As a side note, with any of the affordable options I'm still left with a super awkward looking handset just sitting on a desk. Maybe I can rig up somekind of hanger for them?

Is there a good solution I'm missing? I know a lot of companies are doing this type of thing right now. Are they all just using headsets?

**Edit:** It looks like specific hardware recommendations are off topic which I can understand. How about a class of hardware or type of device? I don't need a specific product, but what kind of product can solve this problem?

Comment: You're still asking us to recommend hardware. All you've done with your edit is asked us to tell you what type of product you need: You need a wireless headset, apparently. The right piece of equipment for you depends on a wide variety of factors, not all of which can be conveyed in this format, and comes down to personal preference. These are the key reasons why we avoid recommendation requests and generally close them as off topic.